# Python added directory for scripts to .bashrc but scripts not found

Tags: python, bash, path, pythonpath

I have a directory called `additional-scripts` with a bunch of python scripts inside it I would like to run. I added it to my `.bashrc` file like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/lkloh/pysmo/pysmo-aimbat/additional-scripts
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Users/lkloh/pysmo/pysmo-aimbat/additional-scripts
```

However, the python scripts in the directory `additional-scripts` are not deteched when I try to run them on the terminal. For example, I have a file called `foo.py` inside directory `additional-scripts`, but when I try to run `foo.py` in terminal, it says

```
-bash: foo.py: command not found
```

How to make the system detect `foo.py`?

EDIT:

Turns out I had to source my .bashrc' file inside my.profilefile. So inside.profile, you do 
    source .bashrc
and all the scripts whose path I added to my.bashrc` file can now be found.

Comment: Have you checked if `foo.py` has execute permissions?

Comment: Also yeah, I had to do `./foo.py` to run it once I actually managed to source the file.

Comment: It's not a good idea to source `.bashrc` (which might contain `bash`-specific code) from `.profile` (which could be used by any POSIX-compliant shell). Rather, use `.bash_profile`, which should first source `.profile`, then do `bash`-specific configuration, then source `.bashrc`. The path modifications themselves can go in `.profile`.